# Why do we use synchronized keyword while our aim of using multi-threading is parallel computing?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

How can parallel computing be achieved when using the synchronized keyword to allow only one thread at a time in Java multi-threading? Can you provide a comprehensible coding example to demonstrate parallel computing with a synchronized keyword?

Here's the sample code that demonstrates how to achieve parallel computing with synchronized keywords:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class Counter {
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public synchronized void increment() {
        count.getAndIncrement();
    }
}

public class SyncDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Counter c = new Counter();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
                    c.increment();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
                    c.increment();
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println("Count: " + c.count);
    }
}
```

In this modified code, the Counter class uses the AtomicInteger class to implement the count variable. The AtomicInteger class provides thread-safe operations that can be used without the need for synchronization.

By using AtomicInteger instead of a regular integer, we can avoid using synchronized blocks and still achieve thread safety. This allows multiple threads to increment the counter variable concurrently, which leads to parallel computing.

In conclusion, using AtomicInteger instead of regular integers is an efficient way of achieving parallel computing while maintaining thread safety in Java multi-threading.

N.B: *This code is from a YouTube video.*

Comment: Well not in this example, as you have correctly identified. You just picked a bad example for showing parallel computation. You cannot increment a single counter in parallel and expect to get correct results, but you can do other things in parallel!

Comment: Why is this question about Java tagged C#? Don't try to trick people into viewing your question when it's irrelevant to them. Only apply tags that are actually relevant.

Comment: This code is not a great example of parallel computing, but it *is* an example of safe concurrency.

Comment: @jmcilhinney. Thanks for your warning. This question is not about java or C# but about multithreading and synchronization concepts.  I guess, in C#, this concept is also present.

Comment: You specifically mention the `synchronized` keyword, which exists in Java but not in C#. If you want to talk about more general concepts, you should not ask questions about language-specific keywords.

Comment: You may find [this short example in the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) informative.  Without synchronization or locks, threads may not see changes made by other threads.

Answer (score 1):

Your two threads mutate a shared state, the counter. As incrementing in Java is not an atomic operation, `count++` is what's called a *critical section* which must be protected from being entered by more than one thread at a time. For this, your code uses the `synchronized` keyword on method `increment()`.

If you want to count in parallel, just don't share the counter.

Give each thread its own Counter instance, then `increment()` will never be called by more than one thread on an instance of Counter at a time. No more thread synchronization is needed *there*.

That doesn't mean that you don't have to coordinate the threads at all: as you want to output the total count, this can only be done if all threads have finished their work. One way is to join the threads like your main method does. Afterwards you can output the sum of the individual counts.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we use `synchronized` keyword while our aim of using multi-threading is parallel computing?

We don't.

If our aim of using multi-threading is parallel computing,* then we try to design our program to use `synchronized` only when it is absolutely necessary for the threads to talk to each other. We try to make sure that that seldom happens.

The best parallel computations allow the threads to run independently of each other, each working on its own private data (or, its own private *copy* of some "shared" data), for long stretches at a time. Then they sync up only just long enough to maybe update a few shared variables and continue.

You often will see things in parallel algorithms that look wasteful: E.g., A thread does some work, and then when it syncs up with the shared database, it sees that the work was not necessary, and it throws the result away before starting another task.

Sounds wasteful, but if that strategy allows seven other threads to do big chunks of useful work without needing to talk to each other, it pays off in the long run.

---

* That's not always our aim of using multi-threading. Our aim of using multi-threading is always to achieve *concurrency.* Sometimes we want the threads to concurrently compute something (a.k.a., "parallel computation,") but other times, we want our threads to concurrently *wait* for events that are driven by external, unsynchronized sources (e.g., in a server that waits for commands from multiple different clients.)